# How Capture video from camera in grayscale mode?

Tags: directshow

Look at this code i've written so far to capture video/audio from camera with directshow:
https://gist.github.com/LinArcX/b43ce8b1905b165de2314e6f9b202c8c

It works but it uses `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24` and the result is colorful. I want to remove colors and have a grayscale video as output. Someone said that i can use YUV subtype and remove UV from it. But i don't have any idea how do that in my code.